# What is the preferred way to check whether a program exists with bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a script that will run several versions of a program written in different languages so it should be able to detect if the system can run a file first. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) somewhat useful, but I would like to know if my existing code could be improved instead.

I use the following approach to check if a program exists.

```bash
if type "$PROGRAM" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  # OK
fi
```

I was debating whether this question should go in Code Review, but I decided to post it here as it's just 2 lines of code.

Comment: I would use `type -P` or `command -v`

Comment: I read somewhere that `type -P` may not be very portable. Just saying.

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:bash], so I gave you some bash specific options. I personally find portability over-rated: bash itself is widely installed, so code for bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this in bash:

```
# Convenience method to check if a command exists or not.
function command_exists {
  hash "$1" &> /dev/null
}
```

And that gives me a `command_exists`:

```
if command_exists "vim"; then
  echo "and there was great rejoicing!"
fi
```

Or in one offs:

```
command_exists "vim" && echo "and there was great rejoicing!"

function die {
  echo "$1"
  exit 1
}
command_exists "vim" || die "Vim needs to be installed"
```

Comment: Do you have any opinions for choosing `hash` over `type`? Preference? According to the linked answer, `hash` may not modify `$?` in some shells (it does not state which shells though). +1 I like `hash` in that there is no output in case of success.

Comment: If this was a script that would run in more then just bash then yes type is probably a better choice. But hash works on all the bash shells I've encountered so it works well for me.